# ModuleNotFoundError: python import extern module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I struggle with importing Pillow in my python code.

My import statements:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import pillow
```

I use an local Anaconda interpreter (Anaconda 3) where I installed pillow:

```
conda install -c anaconda pillow
```

If I check with `conda list` there is a pillow-package...

Pycharm still throws: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'`

There were no errors during pillow installation...
I tried restarting pycharm, reboot, uninstall / reinstalling pillow

I have no further idea what I can do, would be great if someone can help me :)

I'm working with pycharm 2017.3 on Windows 7 (64bit)

Kind regards, Lukas

Comment: I suspect you have to choose a right interpretator in Pycharm, which is Anaconda in your case. If you need i could elaborate on how

Comment: Which python did your pycharm show? In `Preferences -> Project -> Project intepreter`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments... My Project Interpreter is Python 3.6 (...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe). In the Package-List of the Interpreter in Pycharm there is a Package 'Pillow' (Version 4.3.0)'...